# host:port pair: PBUF

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Versions that I'm using, Hadoop 2.2.0 and HBase 0.96.1.1, Hive 0.12.0 in all nodes

Anyone can explain this error that is giving me?

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
test(key string, values map<string, int>)
STORED BY
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,values:"

TBLPROPERTIES (
"hbase.table.name" = "test"
);

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Not a host:port pair: PBUF
hadoop-master�����޹(
```

The only configuration that I made from Hive is this:

```
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>local</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is most probably due to version mismatch between HBase server and the HBase client jars shipped with Hive 0.12

To confirm, please do `cd <hive_directory>/lib` and `ls hbase*.jar`. The version of jars in hive lib should match with your hbase server installation.

If the versions are different, you can try copying the hbase jars from your hbase installation to hive lib directory.

Comment: i have to delete the older hbase jar? i'm seeing hbase-0.96.1.jar(old) and i put the new one hbase-hadoop2-compat-0.96.1.1-hadoop2.jar in hive/lib

Comment: Yes, you need to delete the older ones and put new ones there.

Answer (score 0):

Its a version problem 
Used hadoop 2.2.0 + Hive 1.2.1 + HBASE 0.98.15
then updated hive lib jars for hbase compatibility and resolve the issue.